# Windows 8 Annoying System Beep Sound

Tags: audio, windows-8.1

I use ConEmu and R programming REPL. Problem with this beautiful setup is that windows 8 starts making annoying beeping sounds

I googled and found that many people solved this by devmgmt.msc -> show hidden devices -> non plug and play -> beep and disabled it.

However it has been noted that windows 8 does not have "non plug and play" option in devmgmt.msc

then people suggested that I go into "change system sounds" -> default beep and set it to none.

I did it ... rebooted... but my system is still beeping and its driving me mad. windows 8 is driving me mad.

Please ... can someone tell me how to kill this beeping sound... please....

Comment: You have not said when these beeps occur.

Comment: If I run "r" in the console. move to some other application then come back to my console. it starts beeping. So far what I have done is clicked on the "mixer" icon in the task bar and then muted the "system sounds"... however this will not last reboots.

Comment: "Come back" - how do you do that?

Comment: R is a programming language which has a REPL. so If I run r.exe in the console. then go to some other application (like chrome) and then click back in the console. the console starts beeping infinitely. Now I know that the "console" is not at fault as R may be making the noise... but I need to switch the noise off.

Comment: Option "Skip click activation" or so

Comment: same problem. switched skip click activation to off. switched between windows couple of times and the annoying beeping was back.